# Bash script for printing Heart shape

Tags: linux, bash, terminal

i want to write a bash script to echo a shape(heart) that made of strings and draw it in Terminal. like this picture:
i find a bash script but it didn't work.

[image: Picture]

```
echo '\x1f\x8b\x08\x00\x95\x10\xe0R\x02\xffSPP\xf0\xc9/KU\x80\x03\x10\x8f\x0bB\xa1c.l\x82dJ\xe0\xb0\x01\xe6\x02\x0cATa.T\xf7\x02\x00\xd9\x91g\x05\xc5\x00\x00\x00'|gunzip
```

i find above code and tried it, but it didn't work.

Comment: Use `echo -e` with `bash`.

Comment: I highly doubt you're figure out to edit that hex string to replace `Love` with some other string; best bet is to follow the steps I outlined in my answer ... create a file with the desired textual 'image', `gzip` the file, and then convert the *gz flle to its equivalent hex string; I'm not sure about how to convert the *gz to a hex string ... so perhaps ask that as a new question?

Comment: @Ryan: To create your own string from a file with `hexdump`: `gzip <file | hexdump -v -e '"\\x" 1/1 "%02X"'; echo '\x00'` Then use `echo -en '...'` or `printf '...'`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Background:**

Someone created a text file with the textual image of the heart; let's call the file `heart`.

Then they (likely) zipped the file with `gzip`, eg: `gzip heart` which generated the file `heart.gz`.

At this point if you ran the file through `gunzip` and dumped the results to stdout you'd get:

```
$ gunzip -c heart.gz
   Love          Love
  LoveLoveLoveLoveLove
LoveLoveLoveLoveLoveLove
LoveLoveLoveLoveLoveLove
LoveLoveLoveLoveLoveLove
  LoveLoveLoveLoveLove
    LoveLoveLoveLove
      LoveLoveLove
          Love
```

You could also generate the same results by `cat`ing the `heart.gz` and then piping the output to `gunzip`, eg:

```
$ cat heart.gz | gunzip
   Love          Love
  LoveLoveLoveLoveLove
LoveLoveLoveLoveLoveLove
LoveLoveLoveLoveLoveLove
LoveLoveLoveLoveLoveLove
  LoveLoveLoveLoveLove
    LoveLoveLoveLove
      LoveLoveLove
          Love
```

**Current question:**

Instead of uploading the `heart.gz` file and then requiring the download of said file, the originator (in essence) converted `heart.gz` to its equivalent string of hex codes.  This eliminated the need to upload the `heart.gz` file.

Now, intead of running the file (`heart.gz`) through `gunzip`, the user can `echo` the hex string to stdout (basically generate the same output as `cat heart.gz`), which is then piped to `gunzip`, with the net result that the command you're asking about should generate the image in question:

```
$ echo '\x1f\x8b\x08\x00\x95\x10\xe0R\x02\xffSPP\xf0\xc9/KU\x80\x03\x10\x8f\x0bB\xa1c.l\x82dJ\xe0\xb0\x01\xe6\x02\x0cATa.T\xf7\x02\x00\xd9\x91g\x05\xc5\x00\x00\x00'|gunzip
   Love          Love
  LoveLoveLoveLoveLove
LoveLoveLoveLoveLoveLove
LoveLoveLoveLoveLoveLove
LoveLoveLoveLoveLoveLove
  LoveLoveLoveLoveLove
    LoveLoveLoveLove
      LoveLoveLove
          Love
```

**NOTE**: `echo` may not work exactly right depending on your version of `echo`, so you may need to use `echo -e` (as per **Cyrus** comment) or replace `echo` with `printf` (as per **that other guy**'s answer).

Answer (score 3):

Following up my earlier comment (not sure how to convert a *gz file to a hex string) ...

I found I can do something similar with `base64` with the idea being that the base-64 string is going to be easier to work with (ymmv).

Create a file with the desired text 'image', eg:

```
$ cat heart
   Love          Love
  LoveLoveLoveLoveLove
LoveLoveLoveLoveLoveLove
LoveLoveLoveLoveLoveLove
LoveLoveLoveLoveLoveLove
  LoveLoveLoveLoveLove
    LoveLoveLoveLove
      LoveLoveLove
          Love
```

Run the file through `base64` to generate a base-64 (as opposed to hex==base-16) string representing the contents of the file, eg:

```
$ base64 heart
ICAgTG92ZSAgICAgICAgICBMb3ZlCiAgTG92ZUxvdmVMb3ZlTG92ZUxvdmUKTG92ZUxvdmVMb3ZlTG92ZUxvdmVMb3ZlCkxvdmVMb3ZlTG92ZUxvdmVMb3ZlTG92ZQpMb3ZlTG92ZUxvdmVMb3ZlTG92ZUxvdmUKICBMb3ZlTG92ZUxvdmVMb3ZlTG92ZQogICAgTG92ZUxvdmVMb3ZlTG92ZQogICAgICBMb3ZlTG92ZUxvdmUKICAgICAgICAgIExvdmUK
```

At this point you can use following modified command to `echo` the above string and then pipe it through `base64 -d` (ie, replace `gunzip), eg:

```
$ echo "ICAgTG92ZSAgICAgICAgICBMb3ZlCiAgTG92ZUxvdmVMb3ZlTG92ZUxvdmUKTG92ZUxvdmVMb3ZlTG92ZUxvdmVMb3ZlCkxvdmVMb3ZlTG92ZUxvdmVMb3ZlTG92ZQpMb3ZlTG92ZUxvdmVMb3ZlTG92ZUxvdmUKICBMb3ZlTG92ZUxvdmVMb3ZlTG92ZQogICAgTG92ZUxvdmVMb3ZlTG92ZQogICAgICBMb3ZlTG92ZUxvdmUKICAgICAgICAgIExvdmUK=" | base64 -d
   Love          Love
  LoveLoveLoveLoveLove
LoveLoveLoveLoveLoveLove
LoveLoveLoveLoveLoveLove
LoveLoveLoveLoveLoveLove
  LoveLoveLoveLoveLove
    LoveLoveLoveLove
      LoveLoveLove
          Love
```

NOTE: `base64 -d` == convert from base-64 to the original contents of the file.

---

For a smaller string you can `gzip` the `heart` file first and then run the *gz file through `base64`, eg:

```
$ gzip heart
    => generates file heart.gz
$ base64 heart.gz
H4sICHSiC14AA2hlYXJ0AFNQUPDJL0tVgAMQjwtCoWMubIJkSuCwAeYCDEFUYS409wIAcgvdzcYAAAA=
```

Then to get back to the image we have to run the steps in reverse:

```
echo "H4sICHSiC14AA2hlYXJ0AFNQUPDJL0tVgAMQjwtCoWMubIJkSuCwAeYCDEFUYS409wIAcgvdzcYAAAA=" | base64 -d | gunzip
   Love          Love
  LoveLoveLoveLoveLove
LoveLoveLoveLoveLoveLove
LoveLoveLoveLoveLoveLove
LoveLoveLoveLoveLoveLove
  LoveLoveLoveLoveLove
    LoveLoveLoveLove
      LoveLoveLove
          Love
```

Comment: it worked GREAT! thank you very much. i can't submit "useful vote", but i did it.

Comment: good to hear ("*It worked*"); as for the missing vote ... *darn* ... and here I was hoping to use those extra points to buy dinner tonight! :-)

Answer (score 1):

It's tricky to get exact binary output with `echo` because implementations differ a lot.

In bash, you can instead do this with `printf` (other shells vary because `\x` escapes are not portable):

```
$ printf '\x1f\x8b\x08\x00\x95\x10\xe0R\x02\xffSPP\xf0\xc9/KU\x80\x03\x10\x8f\x0bB\xa1c.l\x82dJ\xe0\xb0\x01\xe6\x02\x0cATa.T\xf7\x02\x00\xd9\x91g\x05\xc5\x00\x00\x00'|gunzip
   Love          Love
  LoveLoveLoveLoveLove
LoveLoveLoveLoveLoveLove
LoveLoveLoveLoveLoveLove
LoveLoveLoveLoveLoveLove
  LoveLoveLoveLoveLove
    LoveLoveLoveLove
      LoveLoveLove
          Love$
```

Note that the compressed contents is not linefeed terminated, so the next prompt will appear on top of the heart.